# Dynamically change two columns used in a Measure

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to calculate multiple measures that are just the same, but different in two columns related to the product chose:

```
 All Users CB =  CALCULATE(
     DISTINCTCOUNT('retention_monthly'[user_id]),
     'retention_monthly'[OnlineCashback_days] > 0,
     USERELATIONSHIP(_Calendar_Vintage[Date], cross_selling[first_online_cashback_date]),
     ALLSELECTED(_Calendar) )
```

We have four products, so I would have to copy the same measures once for each.
[image]

There is any way to create a parameter to choose what service I want to look at and have only one set of measures?

I'm looking for an easy way to replace OnlineCashback_days for OnlineRewards_days and first_online_cashback_date for first_online_rewards_date, with a parameter.

I've noticed that parameters allow me to easly change one measure for another in a chart, but I could not create a list of possible values to use that as a variable to define what column to use. Any hint on how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [calculation groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/calculation-groups?view=asallproducts-allversions)